# R: read.table producing unexpected results on tab delimited data file

Tags: r

I'm a noob to R.  I am running R Studio in Windows and I'm having a heck of a time trying to understand what's happening with the following read.table command.

```
continents=read.table("country2continent.tsv",sep="\t",
  col.names=c("Country","Continent"),fileEncoding = "UTF-8",strip.white = TRUE)
```

Questions:

1. If I try to print a column of data on the command line with the "continents$Country" command, the data is totally garbled.  I examined the garbled data and I found some special characters like "\t" embedded.  What do I have to do to get rid of the special characters that are causing the issues?
2. If I view the continents data frame in R Studio, it almost looks correct. I say almost because examining the R data frame shows that row 61 has an issue.  It should read "Cote d'Ivoire Africa" but actually reads "Cote dIvoire    Africa".  In this row (row 61), the apostrophe is missing in dIvoire and there is a tab between dIvoire and Africa.  There are also a lot of country / continent pairs following "Cote d'Ivoire Africa" that did not get their own rows.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

As per rawr's request, here is a snippet of Sample Data including the problematic row 61:

```
Algeria Africa
Angola  Africa
Benin   Africa
Botswana    Africa
Burkina Faso    Africa
Burundi Africa
Cameroon    Africa
Cape Verde  Africa
Central African Republic    Africa
Chad    Africa
Comoros Africa
Congo - Brazzaville Africa
Congo - Kinshasa    Africa
Côte d’Ivoire   Africa
Djibouti    Africa
Egypt   Africa
Equatorial Guinea   Africa
Eritrea Africa
Ethiopia    Africa
Gabon   Africa
Gambia  Africa
Ghana   Africa
Guinea  Africa
Guinea-Bissau   Africa
Kenya   Africa
Lesotho Africa
Liberia Africa
Libya   Africa
Madagascar  Africa
Malawi  Africa
Mali    Africa
Mauritania  Africa
Mauritius   Africa
Mayotte Africa
Morocco Africa
Mozambique  Africa
Namibia Africa
Niger   Africa
Nigeria Africa
Rwanda  Africa
Réunion Africa
Saint Helena    Africa
Senegal Africa
Seychelles  Africa
Sierra Leone    Africa
Somalia Africa
South Africa    Africa
Sudan   Africa
Swaziland   Africa
São Tomé and Príncipe   Africa
Tanzania    Africa
Togo    Africa
Tunisia Africa
Uganda  Africa
Western Sahara  Africa
Zambia  Africa
Zimbabwe    Africa
Eritrea and Ethiopia    Africa
South Sudan Africa
Sao Tome and Principe   Africa
Cote d'Ivoire   Africa
Reunion Africa
Congo, Dem. Rep.    Africa
Congo, Rep. Africa
Anguilla    Americas
Antigua and Barbuda Americas
Argentina   Americas
Aruba   Americas
Bahamas Americas
Barbados    Americas
Belize  Americas
Bermuda Americas
Bolivia Americas
Brazil  Americas
British Virgin Islands  Americas
Canada  Americas
Cayman Islands  Americas
Chile   Americas
Colombia    Americas
Costa Rica  Americas
Cuba    Americas
Dominica    Americas
Dominican Republic  Americas
Ecuador Americas
El Salvador Americas
Falkland Islands    Americas
French Guiana   Americas
Greenland   Americas
Grenada Americas
Guadeloupe  Americas
Guatemala   Americas
Guyana  Americas
Haiti   Americas
Honduras    Americas
Jamaica Americas
Martinique  Americas
Mexico  Americas
Montserrat  Americas
Netherlands Antilles    Americas
Nicaragua   Americas
Panama  Americas
Paraguay    Americas
Peru    Americas
Puerto Rico Americas
St. Barthélemy  Americas
St. Kitts and Nevis Americas
St. Lucia   Americas
St. Martin  Americas
St. Pierre and Miquelon Americas
St. Vincent and the Grenadines  Americas
Suriname    Americas
Trinidad and Tobago Americas
Turks and Caicos Islands    Americas
Virgin Islands (U.S.)   Americas
United States   Americas
Uruguay Americas
Venezuela   Americas
St.-Pierre-et-Miquelon  Americas
St. Helena  Americas
Sint Maarten (Dutch part)   Americas
Falkland Is (Malvinas)  Americas
Curaçao Americas
Pitcairn    Americas
Cocos Island    Americas
Afghanistan Asia
Armenia Asia
Azerbaijan  Asia
Bahrain Asia
Bangladesh  Asia
Bhutan  Asia
Brunei  Asia
Cambodia    Asia
China   Asia
Cyprus  Asia
Georgia Asia
Hong Kong, China    Asia
India   Asia
Indonesia   Asia
Iran    Asia
Iraq    Asia
Israel  Asia
Japan   Asia
Jordan  Asia
Kazakhstan  Asia
Kuwait  Asia
Kyrgyzstan  Asia
Laos    Asia
Lebanon Asia
Macao, China    Asia
Malaysia    Asia
Maldives    Asia
Mongolia    Asia
Myanmar [Burma] Asia
Nepal   Asia
Neutral Zone    Asia
North Korea Asia
Oman    Asia
Pakistan    Asia
West Bank and Gaza  Asia
People's Democratic Republic of Yemen   Asia
Philippines Asia
Qatar   Asia
Saudi Arabia    Asia
Singapore   Asia
South Korea Asia
Sri Lanka   Asia
Syria   Asia
Taiwan  Asia
Tajikistan  Asia
Thailand    Asia
Timor-Leste Asia
Turkey  Asia
Turkmenistan    Asia
United Arab Emirates    Asia
Uzbekistan  Asia
Vietnam Asia
Yemen   Asia
Myanmar Asia
Lao Asia
United Korea (former)   Asia
South Yemen (former)    Asia
North Yemen (former)    Asia
Albania Europe
Andorra Europe
Austria Europe
Belarus Europe
Belgium Europe
Bosnia and Herzegovina  Europe
Bulgaria    Europe
Croatia Europe
Cyprus  Europe
Czech Republic  Europe
Denmark Europe
East Germany    Europe
Estonia Europe
Faroe Islands   Europe
Finland Europe
France  Europe
Germany Europe
Gibraltar   Europe
Greece  Europe
Guernsey    Europe
Hungary Europe
Iceland Europe
Ireland Europe
Isle of Man Europe
Italy   Europe
Jersey  Europe
Latvia  Europe
Liechtenstein   Europe
Lithuania   Europe
Luxembourg  Europe
Macedonia   Europe
Malta   Europe
Metropolitan France Europe
Moldova Europe
Monaco  Europe
Montenegro  Europe
Netherlands Europe
Norway  Europe
Poland  Europe
Portugal    Europe
Romania Europe
Russia  Europe
San Marino  Europe
Serbia  Europe
Serbia and Montenegro   Europe
Slovakia    Europe
Slovenia    Europe
Spain   Europe
Svalbard and Jan Mayen  Europe
Sweden  Europe
Switzerland Europe
Ukraine Europe
USSR    Europe
United Kingdom  Europe
Vatican City    Europe
Åland Islands   Europe
Åland   Europe
West Germany    Europe
Yugoslavia  Europe
Serbia excluding Kosova Europe
Serbia excluding Kosovo Europe
Slovak Republic Europe
Svalbard    Europe
Kosovo  Europe
Kyrgyz Republic Europe
Czechoslovakia  Europe
Macedonia   Europe
Macedonia, FYR  Europe
Channel Islands Europe
Faeroe Islands  Europe
Holy See    Europe
Akrotiri and Dhekelia   Europe
American Samoa  Oceania
Antarctica  Oceania
Australia   Oceania
Bouvet Island   Oceania
British Indian Ocean Territory  Oceania
Christmas Island    Oceania
Cocos [Keeling] Islands Oceania
Cook Islands    Oceania
Fiji    Oceania
French Polynesia    Oceania
French Southern Territories Oceania
Guam    Oceania
Heard Island and McDonald Islands   Oceania
Kiribati    Oceania
Marshall Islands    Oceania
Micronesia  Oceania
Nauru   Oceania
New Caledonia   Oceania
New Zealand Oceania
Niue    Oceania
Norfolk Island  Oceania
Northern Mariana Islands    Oceania
Palau   Oceania
Papua New Guinea    Oceania
Pitcairn Islands    Oceania
Samoa   Oceania
Solomon Islands Oceania
South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands    Oceania
Tokelau Oceania
Tonga   Oceania
Tuvalu  Oceania
U.S. Minor Outlying Islands Oceania
Vanuatu Oceania
Wallis et Futuna    Oceania
Micronesia, Fed. Sts.   Oceania
Cook Is Oceania
```

Comment: `rl <- readLines('~/desktop/countries.tsv'); dd <- read.table(text = gsub('(.*)\\s+([a-z]+)$', '\\1;\\2', rl, ignore.case = TRUE), sep = ';', quote = '')`

Comment: Thanks a million rawr!  Obviously this question is pretty light work for you.  I ran your code and it looks like it provides me with the cleaned up tab delimited array which I can work with.  I will study your code and learn from it.  If you post your response as an answer I would definitely select your response as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just copied your data to a text file called `countries.tsv` and ran the following code. There may be a way to use `read.table` directly, but this is easier for me.

```
## read in each line of data as a character string
rl <- readLines('~/desktop/countries.tsv')

## this will separate the last word (continent) from the rest of the string
## so this assumes that the second column will _only_ be one word

## (.*)        to 1st capture group any character any number of times
## \\s+        followed by one or more white spaces
## ([a-z]+)$   to 2nd capture group, only take letters a-z one or more times
##               up to the end of the line $

## \\1;\\2     take the two capture groups and separate them with semicolon
txt <- gsub('(.*)\\s+([a-z]+)$', '\\1;\\2', rl, ignore.case = TRUE)

txt[c(1:5, 60:62)]
# [1] "Algeria;Africa"                 "Angola ;Africa"                
# [3] "Benin  ;Africa"                 "Botswana   ;Africa"            
# [5] "Burkina Faso   ;Africa"         "Sao Tome and Principe  ;Africa"
# [7] "Cote d'Ivoire  ;Africa"         "Reunion;Africa"
```

So now that we have a semicolon-separated vector of strings, we can use `text=` in `read.table` very straight-forward. Note that since you have some irregular quotes, eg in line 61 as you pointed out, we also disable quotes with `quote = ''`

```
dd <- read.table(text = txt, sep = ';', quote = '', stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 col.names = c("Country","Continent"), strip.white = TRUE)

# 'data.frame': 290 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ Country  : chr  "Algeria" "Angola" "Benin" "Botswana" ...
#   $ Continent: chr  "Africa" "Africa" "Africa" "Africa" ...

dd[c(1:5, 60:62), ]
#                  Country Continent
# 1                Algeria    Africa
# 2                 Angola    Africa
# 3                  Benin    Africa
# 4               Botswana    Africa
# 5           Burkina Faso    Africa
# 60 Sao Tome and Principe    Africa
# 61         Cote d'Ivoire    Africa
# 62               Reunion    Africa
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to be doing this very often I suggest you download the file and edit it to produce a standard `.csv` format and deal with that.

You can download the file by placing the URL into your browser. There are two columns separated by a `tab`. Put a double quote at the start and end of each line and change the tab to `","`. Change the file type from `.tsv` to `.csv`. It is not obvious that the file is `UTF-8`.

---

OK I copied your file to my HD and used this code in RGUI

This works for me:

```
mytable <- read.table("C:/Users/Philip/Downloads/country2continent.tsv",sep="\t",header=FALSE)  

> head(mytable)
            V1     V2
1      Algeria Africa
2       Angola Africa
3        Benin Africa
4     Botswana Africa
5 Burkina Faso Africa
6      Burundi Africa
```

Comment: I am specifically trying to learn how to process this file with R and not edit the file by hand.

Comment: I used Windows Notepad to determine that it was UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering.  This seems to work pretty good except that the apostrophe's in the data make read.table blow up starting on row 61.  If I add quote='' (which I stole from rawr's answer below) then it seems to work fine.  Again, I really appreciate you taking the time to answer.